# Using UIAppearance to move UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am trying to increase the height of the `UINavigationBar` via `UIAppearance`

The height itself does change but part of the bar is obscured by the device status bar. I would like to move the bar down 22 pixels so it is fully visible:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake([[UINavigationBar appearance] frame].origin.x, 22, [[UINavigationBar appearance] frame].size.width, 103)];
```

And I also set the autoresizing mask

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

But the bar is not translated. Is there another way or another step here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move down only title by this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```